# How to save extracted pitch values in a csv file?

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, feature-extraction, feature-selection

Well I think I should mention it that it's the very first time I'm trying Audio signal processing in Python. I have an audio data set and I am extracting pitch features using Aubio library, and MFCC feature using the python_speech_features library in Python. The thing is, for a single audio file, I am getting around 84 valued vector for the pitch and 12 valued feature vector for MFCC.

Image of extracted pitch feature vector
[image]

So how do I save all these so many values in a single csv file? I have around 700 audio files separated in different directories wrt to emotions. Should I take the mean of all of these values and save them wrt the audio file in a csv? Like this:

[image]

Also, how would I used these values for classification then? 
Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a simple answer to your question.

I have understand that for each data sample you extract a set of features, the same for each sample, don't you?
I suppose you work within a `for` loop, something like this:

```
import numpy as np
all_features = []
for path in path_list:
     x = open_file(path) #an hypothetical function to open your files
     features = extract_features(x) #an hypothetical function to extract features
     all_features.append(features)
```

if your code looks like my simple example, you have created a list `all_features` whose elements `all_features[i]` contains the extracted features from the sample `i`. In addition i suppose that your extracted `features` is a `numpy` vector. If it is not, you should convert it into a `numpy` vector (something like `features = np.array(features)`).

Ok, now you are ready to create a dataset:

```
data = np.vstack(all_features)
```

the vertical stack `np.vstack` generates a matrix of shape `(n_samples, n_features)`. Warning: all features vector must have the same shape!

Now you want to save the dataset, there is on ocean of possibilities, this my favorite three options:
1) using `pandas` to create a `csv` file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv(filename+'.csv', index=False, header=header) #header is a list of string to name columns of csv
#see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandasdocs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html
```

2) dump memory into a pickle file:

```
import six.moves.cPickle as pickle    
with open(filename+'.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)
```

3)save as numpy file:

```
np.save(filename+'.npy', data)
```

Concerning the classification problem, if you want to use a supervised method (MLP, RF, SVM, KNN, ...) you need a class labels (the ground truth), i.e. a vector with shape equals to the number of sample that relates each sample to a integer (for example 0,1 in a binary classification, or 0,1,2,3 for a 4-class classification). This strongly depend from what you want, what is the goal of your training.

Once you have the the data matrix and the label vector, each machine-learning method will be able to classify, if you have enough samples. With this aim, i suggest you to use same augmenting criteria, to have an idea have a look to this [paper](http://karol.piczak.com/papers/Piczak2015-ESC-ConvNet.pdf), it could give you same ideas.

Hoping i have help you, good work!

Answer (score 1):

Python has a built-in csv module.

This [section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer)'s example gives a simple example on how to use a writer to write rows to your csv.